# Phonegap + Blackberry webworks : ant build not generating standardinstall.zip

Tags: blackberry, ant, cordova

I am trying to build a **BlackBerry 7 and earlier** project that uses the **WebWorks SDK** using **Phonegap 2.9**; but the build doesn't generate the StandardInstall.zip file as it's supposed to.

The project I'm trying to build is the **example** app found in the Phonegap 2.9 download (phonegap-2.9.0\lib\blackberry\bbos\example).

I followed the instructions in the Phonegap documentation and there is an overview of my environment:

My OS is Windows XP, I've got JDK, ANT and BlackBerry device manager installed. I've also installed the [BlackBerry Webworks SDK](http://developer.blackberry.com/bbos/html5/download/) and I've setup my Signing Keys (*sigtool.csk* and *sigtool.db* are in the bin folder of the webworks installation).
I also updated the **project.properties** file as explained in the documentation.

When I try to build the app, It doesn't print any error message, but the **OTAInstall** and **StandardInstall** folders are not generated (all I get is the zipped application folder and a widget folder).

I also tried deploying to simulator and to device, the errors thrown confirm just that the build step doesn't generate the files it should.

Screenshots: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XpN4M.png

---

Solutions I already tried:

### JDK version problem

I downgraded JDK to 1.6.0_30 version (it seems that the Webworks SDK doesn't work with upper versions); but it didn't change anything.

### White spaces

I also tried to avoid white spaces in paths like advised in other posts but it doesn't work:

```
C:
├ \ant
├ \java
└ \webworks
```

I don't know what else to do, any help would be much appreciated !

Answer (score 1):

### **To make a blackberry phonegap project, the things you need are:**

1. Phonegap (cordova libs)
2. BlackBerry WebWorks SDK
3. Ant, through which you will build your project.(Also add 'ANT' in you environment variables).

### The steps to create a phonegap build:

1. Open the phonegap sample that came with it. Follow the location -

   ***phonegap-2.3.0\lib\blackberry\sample***
2. Copy cordova folder as you see the sample folder

[image: After you've copied the structure looks like:]

3. Copy lib and www folder also. The lib folder contains the cordova  library. The www   folder is the only place for your files. 
   It contains your html, css, js and the `config.xml`
4. Copy `blackberry.xml`, `build.xml` and `project.properties` files.(change the properties in these files as per your project configurations)
5. 'Build' folder is created once you run the script 'ant blackberry build'(To build the project) or 'ant blackberry load-simulator'(Build and run on simulator) or 'ant blackberry load-device'
6. Once you have built the project you can run it on device using the `.cod` files.

When you run the above build scripts you get the build folder in your **PhonegapBlackberry** project which looks like:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

I've done all of these steps (the only difference is that I downloaded Phonegap 2.9 and not 2.3, which is not supposed to make any difference);

The problem is that when I run _ant blackberry build_ I don't get the OTAInstall and StandardInstall folders; and without any error message I've got a really hard time figuring out what the problem is.

Comment: May be check your properties file. Make sure it has the right sdk location.

Comment: I checked the sdk location which is set like this:
`blackberry.bbwp.dir=C:\\webworks`
(when I put a wrong location I get a build error as expected, so I guess it's not the problem)

Answer (score 0):

Setting the correct Java jdk home path in `bbwp.properties` file of my `<BlackBerry SDK>/bin` folder works for me.

Thanks,
prodeveloper.