# blackberry project using Cordova

Tags: eclipse, blackberry, cordova

if I want to develop a blackberry application using Cordova and eclipse what should I do please tell me from scratch

second thing I want to know what is the difference between blackberry project and blackberry webworks project

Comment: Please read [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), your question as it is will be closed.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO. As Jonathan said you must ask a question properly indicating what you've done so far, what is your problem and what do you expect from us?

Coming to your question: [see this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18853371/phonegap-blackberry-webworks-ant-build-not-generating-standardinstall-zip/18886590#18886590) to learn how to work on a blackberry cordova application from scratch.

A blackberry webworks works and install like a native blackberry project using the html5, css and javascript as a source to development. 
**Source: [blackberry webworks](http://developer.blackberry.com/html5/documentation/what_is_a_webworks_app_1845471_11.html)**

A blackberry project is a native blackberry application written using the standard blackberry jde.

**Source: [blackberry jde](http://developer.blackberry.com/bbos/java/download/#jde)**